# EmguCV integration with Unity3D on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, mono, emgucv

Been spending the last two days trying to figure this out. I'm trying to use EmguCV to work with Unity3D on my Mac OS (Yosemite, 10.10.2). Using Mono as the editor for code. I've got emgucv installed, but I just can't seem to figure out the setup required for it to work with Unity. I'm currently trying to write a camera capture code, but I'm facing this error:

```
Assets/Scripts/CameraTexture.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Emgu' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

when I do this:

```
using Emgu.CV;
```

I've tried different approaches of copying the various dlls files into the unity project assets folders, but it doesn't change anything.

If anyone has had luck with setting up Emgucv with Unity, please let me know, or point me in the right direction. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get the dlls / binaries? Are you sure they were built for OS X /  mono? Did you try to build them on your own? => http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#OSX

Comment: @d4Rk: I followed those steps for OSX exactly as on the EmguCV page. The dll files are in the bin folder at the emgucv install path. Do you know what steps I need for getting Unity to include emgucv? :/

Comment: @ndhaijaan have you found solution on it?

Comment: @FelikZ Sorry, I never quite managed to make it work.